# pgpoolAdmin - superuser: unknow (connetion error)

Tags: pgpool

After login i got following message.

[image]

create -> /var/www/.pcppass

```
 #insert:hostname:port:username:password

 *:*:admin:postgres
 *:*:postgres:postgres
 *:*:administrator:postges


 host$ sudo chown www-data .pcppass
```

... and it don't works :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long time searching it seems the issue is related to pg_hba.conf and pool_hba.conf incompatibility when using wrong combinations of trusted and md5 host entries. See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71272) and the [FAQ](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/FAQ). Those links shows how to correctly pair both conf files with this matrix :

[image]

You have to set default entries according to this matrix in order to get the so called "superuser" in pgpoolAdmin to be enabled and also to be able to allow connection throught pgpool.

I also found this answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94573) that helped me finally achieving to enable correct connection to backend servers: I had to mark the pgpool server as a trusted server on local network on pg_hba.conf on my postgresql servers.

Comment: Quote the most relevant parts of the link in case the site goes down

Comment: I'm having same issues, while pgpool is working.... (pg_hba and pool_hba are properly set)

However my pgpoolAdmin has other issues aswell:

it says pgpool is down, while it is running
it says my postgresql nodes are down, while they are up
show pool_nodes; -- shows 3 nodes, all up

So the question is: what is wrong? (During setup all requirements were fulfilled and I don't see any errors in apache logfiles)